# What does 嘰咿— mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm reading a Chinese manga translation and have come across this note above a panel: 嘰咿—

I'm not sure what it could mean or say in English. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: If you can provide a scan or a photo of the panel(s) that would be even better

Answer (score 8):

That looks like onomatopoeia (象声词) so it means exactly what it sounds like: jiyi. In this case though, the 咿 (yi) and the dash (—) are meant to extend the "i" sound, so it's just "jiiiii--" altogether.

[嘰/叽](http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/5630.htm) is usually used for small birds chirping, as in the second definition:

> 2. 象聲詞：小鳥～～叫。

If you look at this list of [Chinese onomatopoeia](http://xh.5156edu.com/page/z2155m1104j18596.html), you may notice that a lot of the characters have the mouth radical (口). When you see a single character or multiple characters all with that radical, especially in a manga, it's very likely that it's an onomatopoeia.

Comment: +1. And I think the case `嘰咿` here describes the sound of rubbing -- like opening a wooden door, some drawer that is not easy to slide, etc.